# group_by is sorting numbers out of order in R

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, grouping, histogram

I'm trying to make a stacked histogram, and have run into issues grouping/sorting data that I haven't been able to resolve. For example, when I group my data, the output says that 100 < 90 (I think because 1 < 9), and I can't figure out how to get R to group using the entire number.

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data
Sims <- seq(1,100,1)
CoOc <- sample(90:140, 100, replace = TRUE)
Out <- sample(c("A Wins", "B Wins", "Tie"), 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(cbind(Sims, CoOc, Out))

# Ordering data for stacked histogram
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(CoOc, Out) %>% # Grouping by CoOc for the x-axis ordering, and then for Out to get outcome (A Wins, B Wins, Tie) grouped together
  summarize(Counts = n())

# Plotting
ggplot(df2)+ 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Out, y = Counts, x = CoOc), 
           position = "stack", stat = "identity")+
  labs(title="Example",
       x="CoOc",
       y="Num")+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Outcome",
                    values = c("#AD1457", "#B3E5FC", "#FF9800"))+
  theme_bw()+ 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"), 
        plot.caption.position = "plot", 
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

Which gives me a plot that looks like this (notice the x-axis initially ascends, but then drops down to a lower number):
[image]

Thanks so much for any help––I'm sorry if this is a dumb question!

Comment: No such thing as a dumb question. Anyway, would be good to include a seed number with `set.seed` when generating fake data, so that the plot provided by answers will resemble yours.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense––I'll make sure to remember that for next time! Thank you! :)

Comment: You can avoid having your numbers converted to characters in your initial creation of the dataframe by not using `cbind`. In this fake data set you don't need cbind, unless that was intentional to replicate your real data characteristics -- that all variables are of type character.

Comment: Oh neat, I didn't know that! Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: That's alphabetic arrangement of numbers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you using the ggplot2 command, just convert the "CoOc" to numeric (x = as.numeric(CoOc)) and then plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data
Sims <- seq(1,100,1)
CoOc <- sample(90:140, 100, replace = TRUE)
Out <- sample(c("A Wins", "B Wins", "Tie"), 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(cbind(Sims, CoOc, Out))

# Ordering data for stacked histogram
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(CoOc, Out) %>% # Grouping by CoOc for the x-axis ordering, and then for Out to get outcome (A Wins, B Wins, Tie) grouped together
  summarize(Counts = n()) 

# Plotting
ggplot(df2)+ 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Out, y = Counts, x = as.numeric(CoOc)), 
           position = "stack", stat = "identity")+
  labs(title="Example",
       x="CoOc",
       y="Num")+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Outcome",
                    values = c("#AD1457", "#B3E5FC", "#FF9800"))+
  theme_bw()+ 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"), 
        plot.caption.position = "plot", 
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image]